# "Messaging payload contains an invalid value for the "data.from_user_id" property. Values must be strings" .How do you even solve this?

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase

So i am trying to work with notifications from device to device and this error is driving me crazy ,i dont know where i am doing wrong.I have tried everything and searched up to my best to solve this,any help is greatly appreciated.Thank you!

This is my FirebaseMessagingClass

```
package com.pappu5.navigation;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class FirebaseMessaging extends 
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

private String channelId = "com.pappu5.navigation";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    String notificationTtile = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String notificationBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    String clickAction = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
    String from_user_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("from_user_id");


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(notificationTtile)
            .setContentText(notificationBody)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

    int notificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();


    Intent intent = new Intent(clickAction);
    intent.putExtra("user_id",from_user_id);

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());

}
```

}

This is Firebase index.js file

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification = 

functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').
onWrite((change, context) => {

const user_id = context.params.user_id;
const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

console.log('We have a notification to send to : ', context.params.user_id);


const fromUser = 
admin.database().ref('/Notifications/'+user_id+'/'+notification_id)
.once('value');
return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {

const from_user = fromUserResult.val().from;
console.log('You have new notification from : ',from_user);
const use_Query = admin.database().ref('Chat_Profiles/'+from_user+'/name').once('value');
const deviceToken = admin.database().ref('/Chat_Profiles/'+ user_id +'/device_token').once('value');

return Promise.all([use_Query,deviceToken]).then(result => {
 const userName = result[0].val();
 const token_id = result[1].val();
 const payload = {
  notification: {
   title: "Friend Request",
   body: userName+" has sent you request",
   icon: "default",
   click_action : "com.pappu5.navigation_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"  //change this line
  },
  data : {
   from_user_id: from_user
  }
 };

 return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id,payload).then(response => {
  return console.log('This was the notification feature');
 });
});


});


});﻿
```

Comment: When you print the value of `from_user`, what does it show?

Comment: It says  "'You have new notification from : undefined'"
Also if i remove the code whatever is related to "from user"
I get the notification to my mobile like this "Null has sent you a request"

Comment: Ok, so that means that `fromUserResult.val().from` is not a defined field in that path. I'd check `fromUserResult.val()` first and make sure the field name is correct.

Comment: Thats was awesome ! the "values must be strings "error is gone now but now a new error has popped up i.e

Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "/Chat_Profiles/[object Object]/name". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"